# Why did it take Jack-52 three years to find the cabin?

Tags: oblivion

In the 2013 film [Oblivion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblivion_(2013_film)), protagonist Jack finds out that he is actually

> one of many clones made from the original Jack. During the course of the film, we see Jack (Jack-49) meet another clone, Jack-52. About mid-way through the film, Jack-49 conceives a daughter with love interest Julia.

At the end of the film, we witness

> Jack-52 arriving at the lakehouse where Julia and her daughter - now a toddler - are living.

**Why did it take Jack-52 three years to show up, and where was he during that time?**

Comment: Because he's a schmuck

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My understanding is that

> Jack-49 built the cabin himself during his frequent trips, where he'd disappear off Victoria's radar, sometimes for days.

Even though

> Jack-52 is another clone, he wouldn't possess Jack-49's memories from the moment of "activation".  This includes anything Jack-49 did during his service.

It takes him this long to find the cabin because

> Jack-52 doesn't know where it is, or even if it exists at all - only a feeling that he would also build one somewhere safe.

The areas Jack and Victoria are servicing is very large, and without assistance of flyers and monitors, it takes him this long to search for it on foot.  He is closely followed by

> what appears to be the remnants of Scavs, so we can assume he's been helping them survive during his search.

Comment: This could be the answer. I was under the impression that the Scavs were bringing HIM to the cabin, not the other way around, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Omegacron I think they were searching for the cabin together.  Beech told Jack that he's seen him take "souvenirs" every now and then, so Scavs know Jack has a safe place somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like a plot hole.

Since Malcolm Beech was in on the plan of using a second pod to smuggle his badly wounded self into the Tet in Julia's place, it seems very implausible that he never told any of the Scavs where Julia's pod went (like the Sergeant Sykes portrayed by Coster-Waldau). Especially since Julia selflessly volunteered her life for the sake of destroying the Tet it doesn't make much sense that none of the Scavs would care what happened to her.

Since he flew Julia to the cabin using the bubble ship before returning to the Scav base to pick up Malcolm Beech with a second cryopod, it seems implausible that he wouldn't bring a Scav with him for security and to show him the way.

There is no in-universe explanation for this, but story & production-wise it allowed them to use a young child actor instead of an infant to portray their daughter when Jack-52 arrives with the Scavs.

Answer (score 0):

I think Julia was already pregnant and had the embryo inside her during her stasis. That she was shot in the stomach makes it a bit hard to fathom the embryo's survival, but, she may have only conceived the day before going into the pod and so the tiny embryo could well have been far enough away from the trauma of the wound to have escaped damage.
Why do I think this? Well as a clone, Jack 49 would be sterile and so was Victoria. Their relationship was sexual but she never conceived.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  The question isn't about Julia, it was about Jack-52, and why it took him 3 years to find the cabin.  When Julia got pregnant, and by whom, doesn't really matter.

Comment: I'm not sure clones are really sterile either